# Dockerfile for React App with Node and Nginx image for deploying on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, kubernetes, devops

I am facing difficulty in creating Dockerfile for My test React app. My goal is to deploy React App into Kubernetes cluster locally.  I have successfully used nginx image but facing issue while running my  node backend startup file. I can see the UI successfully on my browser but its not connecting properly with Backend. I have used SQL server for database & node for backend.

This is my Dockerfile

```
#Stage1
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 9005
#CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]




#Stage2
FROM nginx:1.17
COPY view/ /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD  [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

I have followed [this](https://dev.to/rieckpil/deploy-a-react-application-to-kubernetes-in-5-easy-steps-516j) guide for reference. I will really appreciate if you help me.

Comment: You should be able to run a script in your `package.json` like `yarn build` to get static files out.  Then you can `COPY --from=build` in your second build stage to get those static files into the nginx image.  (Or just run `yarn build` outside of Docker, and move the static files to somewhere that's convenient to host them.)

Comment: Thanks for replying.I am following this guide
https://medium.com/greedygame-engineering/so-you-want-to-dockerize-your-react-app-64fbbb74c217

but facing bit issues in building an app as my Build is in other folder not in default. I have tried something like this "build": "react-scripts build && mv build view"  in my package.json as my build is in View folder.